# Merge the changes done on the origin to my private branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I am on my private branch now (`new01`),

What are the commands which will update this branch to all the changes made in the mainline (origin)?

I have tried the following:

```
C:\GIT\abcd>git branch 
*new01
master
C:\GIT\abcd>git fetch origin
C:\GIT\abcd>git merge origin new01
Already up-to-date
```

But the branch `new01` is not updated yet with the latest changes in master.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your branch and merge like this

```
git checkout new01
get merge origin
```

this will create a new commit into your branch new01.